# How to define _tagert="blank" with echo statement getting variables

Tags: php

I am trying to get a link to open to a blank web viewer page using an echo statement that pulls two variables to create the link.

The following shows my last attempt.

```
echo "<a target="_blank" href=$link>$media</a>";
```

I'm getting a syntax error but have gone blank as to where it is.

Comment: You should [escape qoutes in your string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php). `echo "<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"{$link}\">{$media}</a>";`

Answer (score -1):

You should escape double quotes. Also, as a rule of thumb, use `htmlspecialchars` when composing html attributes:

```
echo sprintf('<a target="_blank" href="%s">%s</a>', htmlspecialchars($link), $media);
```